# CodeIgniter - validation not happens

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I am doing a validation using Code Igniter. I have a simple form which used to create / update a product record.

```
public function productSave($params) {
    if (!$this->validate($params)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $id_col_value = $params['product_id'];

    if ($id_col_value) {
        // update
        $this->db->where("product_id", $id_col_value);
        return $result = $this->db->update("product", $params);
    } else {
        // insert
        return $result = $this->db->insert("product", $params);
    }
}
```

My validation function looks like this,

```
protected function validate($params) {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("name", "", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_data($params);
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        $errors = $this->form_validation->error_array();
        if ( $errors ){
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

### Now the problem

When inserting (when `product_id` is null) it validates. But when we have a `product_id` it does not validates.

My payload (`$params`) looks like this,

```
Array
(
    [product_id] => 1 // this is NULL when we do inserting
    [name] => Test Name
)
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here and why the validation not work for updating. I use the same code for both cases.

Please Help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out.

> "We have to call the set_data() method before defining any validation
>   rules."

Which is in the [Documentation](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post) of CI.

So, basically, I call `$this->form_validation->set_data($params);` first
and then, I call `$this->form_validation->set_rules("name", "", "trim|required");`.

This will solve the problem.

Hope this helps anyone with the same error!!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your `params` array. I have checked it using `$params = array("product_id" => 34, "name" => "Test Name")` & it's working perfectly.
2. If you have no inserted data with that product_id, it will not work. Suppose you have passed `product_id=3` & this id is not available in table. Then how should it work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still don't work for me. Can this behavior be varied on the REQUEST type? I use POST to insert and PUT to update.

Comment: share your html/view